# Bad gateway using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, ubuntu-14.04, multer

I get an issue using NodeJS to upload files.

The issue is appear when the connexion of the user is very slow, with a normal connexion everything works.

**Error message :**

```
Bad Gateway
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxxxxxxx Port 80
```

**My code :**

```
app.use(multer({
  dest: './public/uploads/',
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10485760 // 10485760 octets = 10mo -- 7340032 octets = 7 mo -- = 819200 octets = 800 ko --- 102400 octets = 100 ko --- 5242880 octets = 5 mo
  },
  onFileSizeLimit: function(file) {
    console.log('Failed: ', file.originalname);
    fs.unlink('./' + file.path);
  },
  onFileUploadComplete: function() {}
}));
```

I don't think that the issue is due to my NodeJS code but it could be an issue with Apache...